# Is it possible to get more control out of this CSS animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I started animation practice today.

I have a 3d box that I am rotating but no matter how big the viewing area is it flies way higher than it needs to and jumps off the page before coming down.

on your particular screen it may just not have enough room but no matter how small I make it , it still overflows the top of the screen.

Also, is it possible to just rotate in place with something like this as well?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/panoptech/pen/mdLjQpV)

I don't think this code is gonna tell enough but stack overflow forced me to put something with the codepen.

```
.perspective {
transform-style: preserve-3d;
--px3d: 50px;
animation: boxanimation 5s linear 1s 
infinite;
}

@keyframes boxanimation {
50% {
transform: rotateX(0deg) 
rotateY(-360deg);
}

100% {
transform: rotateX(360deg) 
rotateY(-360deg);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to rotate your box in place, I would remove the positioning values on the `.box` elements and put them on the `.perspective` container, as that is what you are animating. Those positioning values are likely causing some unintended side effects.

Is this what you were looking for?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(145, 145, 148);
  box-shadow: black 1px 1px 7px, black 2px 2px 10px inset;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: black 3px 3px 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-top: 1%;

}

.front {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, var(--px3d));
  background-color: rgb(1, 220, 249);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, var(--px3d));
  background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, var(--px3d));
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, var(--px3d));
  background-color: rgba(14, 122, 188);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, var(--px3d));
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255);
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, var(--px3d));
  background-color: pink;
}

.perspective {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  --px3d: 50px;
  animation: boxanimation 5s linear 1s infinite;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

@keyframes boxanimation {
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-360deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective">
      <div class="box bottom">Bottom</div>
      <div class="box top">Top</div>
      <div class="box left">Left</div>
      
      <div class="box right">Right</div>
      <div class="box back">Back</div>
      <div class="box front">Front</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thats perfect thank you. It was definitely the div conainter issue and having each box being absolute. Once I adjusted this i can also make the container different sizes and get the animation to do more of what I want as well... (considering its still just me testing things out it doesnt really have a true purpose yet other than learning.) However, I noticed you also added transform-origin: center center; but it doesnt seem to do anything if I have it on or not, so I am going to have to read up on what that does.

Comment: @Sporadic - Please tick the answer to thank Ali and to tell others that this is the answer.